# An elegant aspect for enumerate the equations of a book

Tags: graphics, symbols, color, bold, chngcntr

I am trying to create this kind of enumeration for the various equations of my book, similar, as this image:

[image]

My MWE is:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames, dvipsnames, table, x11names}{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{classico}
\usepackage{pifont}
\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{243,102,25} 
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   Change number equations with sections
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{equation}{section}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\bfseries{\sffamily{\thesection-\arabic{equation}}}\textcolor{ocre}{\ding{228}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\oint \mathbf{E} \cdot d \mathbf{a} = \int \rho \, dv 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\oint \mathbf{B} \cdot d \mathbf{a} =  \mathbf{0} 
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

with this output:

[image]

I have encountered the following problems (see the image below):

[image]

> 1. I don't know how to eliminate the round brackets;
> 2. if we suppose we don't delete the round brackets, the one on the left is not in bold while the one on the right is in bold.
> 3. Using the `pifont` package I was trying to reverse the direction of the arrow to the left using `\rotatebox{...}{...}`, with the `graphicx` package, but I  am not, probably, to rotate the direction of the arrow to the left.

Comment: What should a `\ref` (or `\eqref`) for an equation look like within your text?

Comment: @Werner You're right. I hadn't thought of that. It must appear with round brackets in bold without the symbol. Since I am not good in English and I use the translator, since sometimes my question is not understandable to everyone, can I ask you to edit my question please? Upvote your comment.

Comment: So, something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4tHx.png) (forget the round brackets in the reference). Are you okay with using a user-defined `\eqnref` (rather than `\ref` or `\eqref`)?

Comment: @Werner For both text (`\eqref`) and for the equations, leave the brackets round. For the rest it's ok :-). I have understood that you will have to introduce a new macro for `\eqnref` to get what you can't have by default.

Comment: `\newtagform{Sebastiano}{}{\reflectbox{\textcolor{ocre}{\ding{227}}}}
\usetagform{Sebastiano}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\bfseries{\sffamily{\thesection-\arabic{equation}}}}`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following produces what you're after:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[svgnames, dvipsnames, table, x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pifont}

\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{243,102,25} 
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   Change number equations with sections
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{equation}{section}

\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thesection-\arabic{equation}}
\newcommand{\eqnnumsymbol}{\textcolor{ocre}{\reflectbox{\ding{228}}}}

\makeatletter
\newtagform{bbrackets}% <name>
  [\textbf]% Internal style
  {(}% Left bracket
  {\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\@currenvir}{equation}=0
     \eqnnumsymbol%
   \else
     \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\@currenvir}{align}=0
       \eqnnumsymbol%
     \fi
   \fi
   )}% Right bracket
\makeatother
\usetagform{bbrackets}

\begin{document}

See both~\eqref{eq:eqn1} and~\eqref{eq:eqn2}. Also see~\eqref{eq:eqn3}.

\begin{equation}
  \oint \mathbf{E} \cdot d \mathbf{a} = \int \rho \, \mathrm{d}v \label{eq:eqn1}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  \oint \mathbf{B} \cdot d \mathbf{a} =  \mathbf{0} \label{eq:eqn2}
\end{equation}

\begin{align}
  abc \label{eq:eqn3}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

It uses

- [`mathtools`](//ctan.org/pkg/mathtools)' `\newtagform` to establish a new form of tag for `equation`s and related environments.
- A conditional to set the symbol. If inside an `equation` or `align`, the symbol is added, otherwise it's left out. This allows you to use `\eqref`. It's not extensively tested, but works in the example provided.

---

If you want to remove the **bold** numbering from your reference, you can use the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[svgnames, dvipsnames, table, x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pifont}

\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{243,102,25} 
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   Change number equations with sections
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{equation}{section}

\makeatletter

\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thesection-\arabic{equation}}
\newcommand{\eqnumfmt}{%
  \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\@currenvir}{equation}=0
    \bfseries
  \else
    \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\@currenvir}{align}=0
      \bfseries
    \fi
  \fi}
\newcommand{\eqnnumsymbol}{\textcolor{ocre}{\reflectbox{\ding{228}}}}

\newtagform{bbrackets}% <name>
  [\eqnumfmt]% Internal style
  {(\bgroup}% Left bracket
  {\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\@currenvir}{equation}=0
     \eqnnumsymbol%
   \else
     \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\@currenvir}{align}=0
       \eqnnumsymbol%
     \fi
   \fi
   \egroup)}% Right bracket
\makeatother
\usetagform{bbrackets}

\begin{document}

See both~\eqref{eq:eqn1} and~\eqref{eq:eqn2}. Also see~\eqref{eq:eqn3}.

\begin{equation}
  \oint \mathbf{E} \cdot d \mathbf{a} = \int \rho \, \mathrm{d}v \label{eq:eqn1}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  \oint \mathbf{B} \cdot d \mathbf{a} =  \mathbf{0} \label{eq:eqn2}
\end{equation}

\begin{align}
  abc \label{eq:eqn3}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I've had my doubts. But if I use your code within my book the numbering starts from 1 which is the first chapter or from scratch? I think it starts from scratch and I should change from 0 to 1. Finally, I forgot that there was the command `reflectbox`. I wanted to ask you if you could do an additional edit to delete the bold in the text part that calls the equation.

Comment: @Sebastiano: The equation numbering is *section-equation*, so if you don't have a `\section`, it will be `0`. If you do, it will be `1` or higher. Also remember that `\section`s are number per-chapter; in other words, reset to `0` when you issue `\chapter`.

Comment: My sincere and cordial thanks for your help and for those who appreciated my question in particular.

Answer (score 9):

I propose this other solution, without parentheses, based on  the `\newtagform` command from `mathtools` and the `adforn` ornaments package, which has a left-oriented arrow tip. I took the liberty to change its colour, which suits better the black characters (*quia gustum meum*…). Of course, feel free to choose your own colour if you prefer it:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames, dvipsnames, table, x11names}{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{classico}
\usepackage{adforn}
\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{243,102,25}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Change number equations with sections
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\counterwithin{equation}{section}%
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thesection-\arabic{equation}}
\newtagform{arrowtip}[\bfseries\sffamily]{}{\,\textcolor{IndianRed3}{\Large\adforn{42}}}
\usetagform{arrowtip}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{2}
\setcounter{section}{5}
\begin{equation}
\oint \mathbf{E} \cdot d \mathbf{a} = \int \rho \, dv
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\oint \mathbf{B} \cdot d \mathbf{a} = \mathbf{0}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This does include the entire tag, as-is, in the reference (when using `\eqref`). Something the OP doesn't seem interested in.

Comment: @Werner: You're right (ahd I wouldn't be interested either), but one can play with `cleveref` to solve the problem.

Comment: @Bernard Your proposal is also interesting and I vote for it. I thank you and everyone for your cooperation. I have two different codes. I will try them both :-). Thank you for everything. My sincere greetings and compliments for the Latin language :-)-